# Why does Blackberry java application shows wired dialogs?

Tags: java, blackberry, permissions

My Blackberry 6 java application shows **The application has attempted to open a {0} connection which is not allowed by the application's permissions** error dialog.The application needs internet connection,save data in persistent storage etc...

Why does my application shows such a dialog? Is it requires any permission? How can i set  the requires permissions from my application?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All BlackBerry applications need permissions, most get them on start-up, and they can be changed relatively easily in BlackBerry Options.  Each application should handle the situation when the user does not give them the permissions required.

Unfortunately I can not find a good source that explains this process.  So the best thing I can suggest you do is look at the ApplicationPermissionsDemo that comes as a sample with your IDE.  Then I would do a search on Blackberry Permissions on this forum (and others) to find the issues that other people have had with this process, and the solutions that they have used.